# Customized UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I've got an app with the following class:

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
```

How can I customize UISearchBar?  I'd like to add a segmented button to allow for search options (and/or/phrase).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
search.showsScopeBar = YES;
search.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Button",@"Titles",@"Go",@"Here",nil];
```

That gives you the standard segmented control for search.  You can use `search.selectedScopeButtonIndex` to check its state.

Comment: thanks.  I note for future readers that you also have to add [search sizeToFit], otherwise the search bar will draw at its original size (i'm setting showsScopeBar in viewDidLoad).

Comment: If you are going to filter each scope, what will your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` look like? -- I have a search function and two scope: `City` and `Church`, the search function works, however it will display a blank cell. My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this: `if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        if ([searchBar scopeButtonTitles]) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredResult objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Places"];
        }` Please advice.